# Is there a delay after which crash logs of an app are visible on iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, crash-reports

One of my apps is in the appstore and I got a call from one of our clients saying a specific feature in the application is consitently causing the app to crash. However, I don't see any logs in iTunes Connect rightnow. Is there a delay between the app crashing and the log being submitted? If so, how long does it usually take?

Thanks,
Teja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better asking them to send you crash reports directly. If they sync their handset using iTunes there will be a copy on their PC/Mac.

Unfortunately it seems that people are syncing their phones less and less often. (Which means they never make it into iTC.) Also, not all of them make it into iTC. Apple aggregate them but there also appears to be some level of filtering. What they do is not documented.

This blog explains what I [ended up doing with my apps](http://www.zx81.org.uk/computing/opinion/why-you-need-a-crash-reporter.html).

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if this'll get fixed with iOS5, but till then I'm using this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a service like [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) - They give you real-time crash reports.  You could also use something open-source like PLCrashReporter if you want to implement the server yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The delay really depends on how long it takes before the user syncs their device with iTunes.  I believe after that it's pretty quick.

Also it's worth noting that iTunes Connect needs a few crash reports before it displays them.

Comment: Oh. That's a bummer. I was hoping it'd sync crash logs over the air, but I guess having multiple types of syncs - One for music, apps and another for crash logs doesn't really make that much sense. I'm not sure any of my users will actually go through the effort of syncing with their PCs.